# Error on $.post of Form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to submit a form using JQuery to a PHP page. But I get the following error when I try to run the script from Chrome:

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;       jquery-latest.js;614
```

Line 614 is part of the GlobalEval function.

```
globalEval: function( data ) {
    if ( data && rnotwhite.test( data ) ) {
        // We use execScript on Internet Explorer
        // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
        // rather than jQuery in Firefox
        ( window.execScript || function( data ) {
            window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );
// **** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; **** //
        } )( data );
    }
},
```

This is my code for my form and JQuery submit.

```
<div class="container create-event">
  <form name="new-event" method="post" id="new-event">
    Name of the event: <input type="text" name="event-name"></br>
    Date of the event: <input type="date" name="date"></br>
    Location of the event: <input type="text" name="location"></br>
    Description: <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="description"></textarea></br>
    <a href="#" id="event-submit" class="button red">Submit</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#new-event').submit(function() {
        $.post(
          'post-event.php',
          $(this).serialize(),
          function(data){
            $('#results').html(data);
          }
        );
        return false;
      });
      $('#event-submit').click(
        $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
      );
    </script>
  </form>
  <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Then my 'post-event.php' script is this:

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#event-submit').click(
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
 );
```

After changing the click function into the code below it worked for me.

```
$('#event-submit').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

You were missing the function() reference.